# Execute a method after first is finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

I have some questions , I want to create a program that make connection with database . But I have 2 method to connect :

1. I get a session id from server
2. with this session id I make the connection .

My question is I want to do this while program is launching.
But i put `NSLog` and when i get the session id, and after that i make the connection
my sessionID is null (when the second method is called directly).

But if i call the second method (when i press a button for example) my session_id is not null.

I put this in `dispatch_asynch` but it doesn t work. I don t understand `dispatch_asynch` .
I hope i'm very clear.

Comment: instead of describing the code that is not working, you should post your actual code.

Comment: Use NSOperationsQueue

Comment: @user3351163, Instead of adding answer please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sendAsynchronousRequest`

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
            NSDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
             // Here you can continue 
        }];
```